# PHP Can't find what is wrong with my code (Registration)

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to create a registration form with prepared statements, hashing of passwords, I keep getting "something went wrong message" that i supplied in `else` statement.

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){

   $username = $_POST["username"];
   $password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
   $email = $_POST["email"];

   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
   $stmt->bind_param("sss",$username, $password, $email);

   $stmt->execute();

   $nrows = $stmt->affected_rows;

   if($nrows == 1){
      header("Location: http://localhost/test2/Login.php");}
   else{
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Something went wrong!')</script>";}
}
```

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file reveal? That is where you can precisely read what is wrong in which line in what file. You _can not_ program php scripts without monitoring that file. Unless you are a big fan of endless guessing games.

Comment: What does `$stmt->errorInfo()` tell you?

Comment: @arkascha I tried `echo` the `mysqli errors` and this is what I got: `Data too long for column 'password' at row 1` . My table is created so that my password field is `CHAR(40)` . Should it be something else?

Comment: I asked: "what does your http servers error log file reveal?" A log file is a file where events (errors) are logged into. Take a look at your http servers host definition for the exact location. Typically it is something like `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: Read the bullet point under `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` on the manual page for [password_hash](https://php.net/password_hash). Specifically the part that says `The result will always be a 60 character string, or FALSE on failure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password field in db is CHAR(40).
but the statement

```
password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

is giving 60 char..
That must be a problem.

Comment: This is why using `VARCHAR(255)` unless you have a very compelling reason is a good idea.